# Speeding up SQL Server cross apply to get aggregated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, cross-apply

In SQL Server, I am trying to put together a single query which grabs a row and includes the aggregated data from a two hour window before that row as well as aggregated data from one hour window after. How can I make this run faster?

The rows have time stamps to a millisecond precision, and are not evenly spaced. I have over **50 million** rows in this table, and the query does not seem to be completing. There are indexes in many places, but they don't seem to help. I was also thinking about using a window function, but I am not sure that its possible to have a sliding window with unevenly distributed rows. Also, for the future one hour window, I am not sure how that would be done with a SQL window.

Box is a string and has 10 unique values.
Process is a string and has 30 unique values.
The average duration_ms is 200 ms.
Errors account for less than 0.1% of the data.
The 50 million rows describes a years worth of data.

```
select 
c1.start_time,
c1.end_time,
c1.box,
c1.process,
datediff(ms,c1.start_time,c1.end_time) as duration_ms,
datepart(dw,c1.start_time) as day_of_week,
datepart(hour,c1.start_time) as hour_of_day,
c3.*,
c5.*
from metrics_table c1
cross apply
(select 
    avg(cast(datediff(ms,c2.start_time,c2.end_time) as numeric)) as avg_ms,
    count(1) as num_process_total,
    count(distinct process) as num_process_unique,
    count(distinct box) as num_box_unique
    from metrics_table c2
    where datediff(minute,c2.start_time,c1.start_time) <= 120
    and c1.start_time> c2.start_time
    and c2.error_code = 0
) c3
cross apply
(select
    avg(case when datediff(ms,c4.start_time,c4.end_time)>1000 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as percent_over_thresh
    from metrics_table c4
    where datediff(hour,c1.start_time,c4.start_time) <= 1
    and c4.start_time> c1.start_time
    and c4.error_code= 0
) c5
where
c1.error_code= 0
```

Edit

Version: SQL Azure 12.0

Adding execution plan:
[image]

Comment: I would be surprised if the performance issue is not because of your where predicates. You have functions in your where clause which means you have to calculate datediff for every single row. And in this case you are doing it twice. That means you are performing around 100 million datediff calculations.

Comment: @Hogan I tried to go about windowing, but I did not see an approach that would allow me to go -2 hours from a point in time if the datapoints are not collected in even intervals. Meaning the difference from one row to the next could be a few milliseconds, could be a few seconds, could be minutes

Comment: Yep this isn't possible in the SQL Server implementation (no `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL`) you would have to do some pre aggregation to guarantee one row per minute etc. But `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is not readily compatible with that.

Comment: You do need to get rid of the datediff not because of number of executions but because it makes the query unsargable. You need to get the nested loops joins to do an index seek on errorcode, and then the starttime range, but the query is still likely to be slow. Also is `datediff(hour,c1.start_time,c4.start_time)` really what you want anyway? `00:01` and `01:59` would still have a datediff of 1 as it counts the hour boundaries crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be a step in the right direction...
Note: c2.start_time & c4.start_time are no longer wrappen in DATEDIFF functions making them SARGable...

```
SELECT
    c1.start_time,
    c1.end_time,
    c1.box,
    c1.process,
    DATEDIFF(ms, c1.start_time, c1.end_time) AS duration_ms,
    DATEPART(dw, c1.start_time) AS day_of_week,
    DATEPART(HOUR, c1.start_time) AS hour_of_day,
    --c3.*,
    avg_ms = CASE WHEN 
    c5.*
FROM
    dbo.metrics_table c1
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT
                    AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, c2.start_time, c2.end_time) AS NUMERIC)) AS avg_ms,
                    COUNT(1) AS num_process_total,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT process) AS num_process_unique,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT box) AS num_box_unique
                FROM
                    dbo.metrics_table c2
                WHERE
                    --DATEDIFF(minute,c2.start_time,c1.start_time) <= 120
                    c2.start_time <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -120, c1.start_time)
                    --and c1.start_time> c2.start_time
                    AND c2.error_code = 0
                ) c3
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT
                    AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ms, c4.start_time, c4.end_time) > 1000 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END
                    ) AS percent_over_thresh
                FROM
                    dbo.metrics_table c4
                WHERE
                    --DATEDIFF(HOUR, c1.start_time, c4.start_time) <= 1
                    c4.start_time >= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, c1.start_time)
                    --and c4.start_time> c1.start_time
                    AND c4.error_code = 0
                ) c5
WHERE
    c1.error_code = 0;
```

Of course, making a query SARGable doesn't do any good unless there's an appropriate index available. The following should be good for all 3 metrics_table references... (see what indexes are currently available, there's a chance that you may not need to create a new index)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixf_metricstable_errorcode_starttime ON dbo.metrics_table (
    error_code,
    start_time
    )
INCLUDE (
    end_time,
    box,
    process
    )
WHERE 
    error_code = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `Between` and got good performance in my simple test rig.  I've also used columnstore as 50 million records is DW volumes:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.metrics_table (
    rowId       INT IDENTITY,
    start_time  DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_time    DATETIME NOT NULL,
    box         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    process     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    error_code  INT NOT NULL
);


-- Add records
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT TOP 3334 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) rn
FROM sys.columns c1
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns c3
)
INSERT INTO dbo.metrics_table ( start_time, end_time, box, process, error_code )
SELECT
    DATEADD( ms, rn, DATEADD( day, rn % 365, '1 Jan 2017' ) ) AS start_time,
    DATEADD( ms, rn % 409, DATEADD( ms, rn, DATEADD( day, rn % 365, '1 Jan 2017' ) ) ) AS end_time,
    'box' + CAST( boxes.box AS VARCHAR(10) ) box,
    'process' + CAST( boxes.box AS VARCHAR(10) ) process,
    ABS( CAST( rn % 3000 AS BIT ) -1 ) error_code
FROM cte c
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT TOP 10 rn FROM cte ) AS boxes(box)
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT TOP 30 rn FROM cte ) AS processes(process);


-- Create normal clustered index to order the data
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cci_metrics_table ON dbo.metrics_table ( start_time, end_time, box, process );
--CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cci_metrics_table ON dbo.metrics_table ( box, process, start_time, end_time );

-- Convert to columnstore
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci_metrics_table ON dbo.metrics_table WITH ( MAXDOP = 1, DROP_EXISTING = ON );



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp1' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp1

-- two hour window before, 1 hour window after
SELECT
    c1.start_time,
    c1.end_time,
    c1.box,
    c1.process,
    DATEDIFF( ms, c1.start_time, c1.end_time ) AS duration_ms,
    DATEPART( dw, c1.start_time ) AS day_of_week,
    DATEPART( hour, c1.start_time ) AS hour_of_day,
    c2.xavg,
    c2.num_process_total,
    c2.num_process_unique,
    c2.num_box_unique,
    c3.percent_over_thresh

INTO #tmp1

FROM dbo.metrics_table c1
    CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS num_process_total, 
            AVG( CAST( DATEDIFF( ms, start_time, end_time ) AS NUMERIC ) ) xavg,
            COUNT( DISTINCT process ) num_process_unique,
            COUNT( DISTINCT box ) num_box_unique
        FROM dbo.metrics_table c2
        WHERE c2.error_code = 0
          AND c2.start_time Between DATEADD( minute, -120, c1.start_time ) And c1.start_time
          AND c1.start_time > c2.start_time
        ) c2

    CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT
            AVG( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( ms, c4.start_time, c4.end_time ) > 1000 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END ) percent_over_thresh
        FROM dbo.metrics_table c4
        WHERE c4.error_code = 0
          AND c4.start_time Between c1.start_time And DATEADD( minute, 60, c1.start_time )
          AND c4.start_time > c1.start_time
        ) c3

WHERE error_code = 0
```